# Conceptual issues with references in Java

Tags: java, reference

I am facing a conceptual issue with references in java. This is my implementation of a basic `LinkedList`:

**The Nodes:**

```
class Node {
  int data;
  Node next = null;

  public Node(int data) {
    this.data = data;   
  } 
}
```

**The List:**

```
class LinkedList {  
  Node n = null;
  Node start = null;
  int flag = 0;

  void insertion(int x) {
    if(flag==0)
    {   
      Node newnode = new Node(x);
      n = newnode;
      start = newnode;
      flag = 1;
      return;
    }

    Node newnode = new Node(x);
    n.next = newnode;
    n = n.next;
  }

  void deletion() {
    Node str = start;
    while(str.next.next != null)
      str = str.next;
    str.next = null;        
  }

  void printlist() {
    Node str = start;
    while(str != null) {
      System.out.println(str.data);
      str = str.next;
    }
  }
}
```

**Test Class:**

```
public class Test31 {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    LinkedList ll = new LinkedList();
    ll.insertion(5); 
    ll.insertion(15);
    ll.insertion(25);
    ll.insertion(35);
    ll.insertion(45);
    ll.insertion(55);
    ll.deletion();ll.deletion();
    ll.printlist();
  }
}
```

The above program works perfectly fine without any problem, but if I replace `deletion()` with this piece of code:

```
void deletion() {
  Node str = start;
  while(str.next != null)
    str = str.next;
  str = null;       
}
```

Then deletion of elements does not take place. I am interested in knowing that why this is happening. Using `str.next.next` does the trick, but if I use the deletion method given above shouldn't it also achieve the same effect with just one more iteration of while loop?

Comment: Please format your code prior to posting it. It is very hard to read it like this. You can edit your question.

Answer (score 3):

This is because one of the `str.next` objects still has a reference to it (or potentially `start` is referencing it). By setting `str` to null, you are simply setting the local variable in that method to `null`, but by setting `str.next` to null, you are deleting the reference in that `str` object.

Simple example:

```
Node start = new Node();
Node another = new Node();
start.next = another;
Node toDelete = another;
```

If you do this:

```
toDelete = null;
```

In this case, `toDelete` is now `null`. `start.next` and `another` still contain references to the object `another` was originally assigned to. Even if you append this:

```
another = null;
```

In this case, there's still one reference left. `start.next` still points to the original object that `another` was initially assigned to.

I think the first deletion method is actually incorrect too, as it will never delete the starting node and will throw a `NullPointerException` if you only have one node in it since `start.next` is `null` and the while loop is attempting to get to `start.next.next`. I think this is more accurate:

```
void deletion() {
    Node parent = null;
    Node current = start;
    while (current.next != null) {
        parent = current;
        current = current.next;
    }
    if (parent == null) {
        start = null;
        flag = 0;
    } else {
        parent.next = null;
        n = parent;
    }    
}
```

Comment: I am still unsure @mbaumbach.........as far as scope of str is concerned then if I go with this code:
void deletion(){
  Node str=start;
  while(start.next!=null)
  start=start.next;
  start=null;
  start=str;  
}      
here we have used the class instance variable start then to effect of deletion is not produced.....

Comment: I removed the mentioning of scope, as I think it's only adding confusion since this isn't really a scope issue, it's a reference ownership issue. I wouldn't suggest using the `start` variable as you would be shifting your starting point of your list. When you insert a new node, you are assigning a reference to some other node's `next` variable (or `start` for the first insertion). In order to truly remove it from the list, you need to remove that reference from the owning node.

Comment: that is perfectly fine....I got that.....but I am not able to understand that if I set str.next to null then also class variable start will be pointing to object to which str.next is pointing in that case it should not be gc

Comment: Let's say `start` is Node1, `str` (or `start.next`) is Node2, `str.next` is Node3. If you set `str.next` to `null`, you have removed all references to Node3 and it will be garbage collected. If instead, you set `start.next` to `null`, you have removed all references to Node2 (and thus Node3), so both will be garbage collected.